# run webpack with command line args

Tags: node.js, webpack

I've been trying to pass args from command line to webpack plugin.
I can access the args via process.argv but after that wwebpack fails with error:
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module
It seems that webpack treats the args as folders it needs to find.
This is how I pass the args:
webpack accessKey=myKey

Resolved:

Saw two ways of doing this:

1. Add the param before calling webpack and use the process.env. to access it:
   For example : myparam=1231 webpack 
   in the webpack config file:
   process.env.myparam == 1231
2. Add the args after the webpack command as flags using --.
   For example : webpack --myparam
   in the webpack config file: process.argv[2] == --myparam

Hopes this helps

Comment: Please provide full error message and webpack config

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try passing them before the webpack command:

`accessKey=myKey webpack`

Comment: cool that works when accessing with process.env.accessKey:) Edited post with this response and another way I've found

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it would be best to start a new question.

Comment: @OndrejSevcik, pretty sure you already found the solution. Maybe will help someone, following works for me in npm script "set accessKey=myKey&&webpack ...". In webpack config you can access variable via process.env.accessKey