# Failed to pass command-line arg into Webpack

Tags: node.js, command-line, webpack

I'm trying to pass arguments to Webpack via command like (I got the info from [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2254)):

```
// webpack.dev.conf.js

module.exports = function (env) {
  if (env.compress === 'true') {
    console.log('COMPRESS')
  }
}
```

I did `npm run dev --env.compress` in the terminal. As you can see I'm have custom scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node --max_old_space_size=10000 build/dev-server.js",
```

However, I  get this error:

```
throw new Error("Invalid argument: options");
^
Error: Invalid argument: options
```

How to properly pass command-line arguments to Webpack?

Comment: It's looking for a 'true' string, do you need to pass that like `--env.compress=true`? Also try inputting your options before the 'dev' part: `npm run --env.compress dev`. Related: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590877/run-webpack-with-command-line-args)

Comment: @leocreatini I'm getting the same error ...